# How to resolve spring bean unavailable error?

Tags: spring, hibernate

While running my launcher class i am getting the below error

**Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'roles' available**

My RoleLauncher Class
  // reads spring config java class

```
package come.rahul.spring.launcher;
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RolesConfig.class);
            Roles roles = context.getBean("roles", Roles.class);
```

My RolesConfig.class  is just annotated with @Configuration and @ComponentScan("com.rahul.spring"). Its in the 
**package come.rahul.spring.configuartion;**

My Roles Class is

```
 package come.rahul.spring.entity;
    @Component
    public class Roles {

    private Long roleId;
    private String roleName;
    //getter and setter omitted  for brevity
```

I have one Dao and it's implementaion too

```
package come.rahul.spring.dao;

public interface RolesDao 
{
    //List<Roles> getRoles(); omitted for brevity 
    void print() ;
}
```

Its implementation is below :

```
    package come.rahul.spring.dao;

    @Repository
    public class RolesDaoImpl  implements RolesDao 
    public void print() {
        System.out.println( " Inside Print method of  RolesDaoImpl");
        }

}
```

Comment: Please add your RolesConfig.class to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `@ComponentScan("com.rahul.spring")` but everywhere, you use `package come.rahul.spring;`. You need to use com everywhere instead of come

Comment: Thanks .
I haves Roles pojo thats mirrors the Roles Table in DB and i have DAO and i have DaoImpl for Roles Pojo .

I want to call methods of DaoImpl.

Comment: I don't really follow what this has to do with your initial question. Did you try renaming your packages? Do you still get the same error?